# How to encode a mp4 which has high quality,fast encode speed and low bitrate using FFmpeg API？

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264

I have lots of ARGB binary data and need to encode them to a mp4 file using FFmpeg API.The most difficult things is to deal with the balance between quality,speed and bitrate.

Below is two download links for mp4 files generated from the same ARGB data.

- Generated through FFmpeg API : [MP4 #1](https://github.com/OnlYet/Test-MP4/blob/master/tt_quality.mp4)
- Generated through FFmpeg command line : [MP4 #2](https://github.com/OnlYet/Test-MP4/blob/master/test-out.mp4)

The mp4 generated through command line has high definition and low bitrate(745kbps) while the other has not enough high quality but high bitrate(1009kbps) I don't know the parameters of the mp4 generated through command line but a part of my code is below:

```
 codec_ctx->codec_type = AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO;
 codec_ctx->width = width;
 codec_ctx->height = height;
 codec_ctx->time_base.num = 1;
 codec_ctx->time_base.den = fps;
 stream->time_base = { 1, fps };
if (!strcmp(out_fmt, "mp4"))
    {
        codec_ctx->codec_id = AV_CODEC_ID_H264;
        codec_ctx->bit_rate = 800 * 1000;
        codec_ctx->rc_max_rate = 800 * 1000;
        //codec_ctx->rc_min_rate = 200 * 1000;
        codec_ctx->rc_buffer_size = 500 * 1000;
        /* More gop_size less file size */
        codec_ctx->gop_size = 30;
        codec_ctx->max_b_frames = 3;
        /* Set relevant parameters of H264 */
        codec_ctx->qmin = 10;   //default 2
        codec_ctx->qmax = 31;   //default 31
        codec_ctx->max_qdiff = 4;
        codec_ctx->me_range = 16;   //default 0 
        codec_ctx->max_qdiff = 4;   //default 3 
        codec_ctx->qcompress = 0.6; //default 0.5
        ret = av_dict_set(dict, "profile", "high", 0);
        // Keep a balance between speed and quality when encoding
        ret = av_dict_set(dict, "preset", "superfast", 0);
        ret = av_dict_set(dict, "threads", "0", 0);
        ret = av_dict_set(dict, "crf", "26", 0);    
        // set delay time
        ret = av_dict_set(dict, "tune", "zerolatency", 0);
        return;
    }
```

I know the parameters that affect video quality are mainly these:

> bitrate, "qp", "crf", gop_size, qmin and "preset".

I tried to increase `gop_size` to decrease bitrate but mp4 quality became lower. I also found that the less `crf`, the more quality and the more bitrate. The less `qmin`,the more quality and the more bitrate. And preset a higher encode speed, the more bitrate.

In fact, I want to set "preset" to ultrafast and set "crf" to 20 but the output mp4 will be larger.So why the mp4 generated through command line can be high quality but low bitrate? How to set the parameters of `AVCodecContext` to generate a mp4 with high quality,low bitrate and high speed?

**Supplementary notes** ：
The mp4 generated through command line stay low bitrate most of the time and higher bitrate sometimes but my mp4 is always stay relatively high bitrate. I think the point is to control the bitrate.